# Issue with importing scipy.integrate or scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: scipy

This might be something really simple: I am using Python 2.6.5 and I am unable to load any integration module in my working space. Everything is OK when I import scipy, but if I try to import scipy.integrate or scipy.integrate.quad I get an error message from python. Any clue?? Thanks.

Comment: What error message would that be?

Comment: A window labelled "pythonw.exe" pops up.

Comment: It says: "pythonw.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience". Not very enlightening I believe...

Answer (score 0):

Try `from scipy import integrate`.

Comment: I did but it doesn't work (i.e. it gives me an error message that makes python restart).